# Checking if schema name is included in every sentence

Tags: oracle, schema, scripting

I got some oracle database scripts for creating the whole database of an application, including sentences for creating tables, sequences, synonyms, inserts and updates of data, etc

I need to ensure that all these sentences have the schema name before table name, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMANAME.MYTABLE...
```

I need to check this for each sentence, regardless of whether they are creates, inserts, foreign keys sentences, etc.

And here is the question, ¿is there a way to do this kind of check? maybe through sqldeveloper tool setting a specific configuration?

Maybe the right question here could be also, if is there a way to execute the script and show an error when the executed sentence has not the schema name included?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a different user/schema to run the script then the one you want the objects in? Seems like it would be best to either use the user/schema or have the user that is running the script proxy in as the schema to ensure that they are in the proper place.

Comment: i could run the script with the same user or with an sys user for example. I dont understand how to do the second part of ur comment when you say "have the user that is running the script proxy in as the schema to ensure that they are in the proper place".thx